# java SunPKCS11 multiple etokens(smartcards) same time , provider not found error

Tags: java, ssl, keystore, smartcard, pkcs#11

I am using SSL connection with X509 certificates provided from smartcards.
I have 2 identical tokens from athena . I initialise the keystores after I am reading the certificates, but when I am trying to to do the actual connection for the second token I am getting no provider found for my Private key.Connecting using the first token it's not affected, it works.
I tried adding different SunPCKS11 provider by specifing the slotIndexList to 1 , the number for the second token given by "slots = p11.C_GetSlotList(true)", but still the same error.
When I am listing the providers: I see the second provider, but java doesn't use it (I don't know why).

```
Provider _etpkcs11;
slots = p11.C_GetSlotList(true);

if(slot ==0) 
{
String pkcs11config = "name=Athena\nlibrary=C:\WINDOWS\system32\asepkcs.dll";
byte[] pkcs11configBytes =pkcs11config.getBytes();
 ByteArrayInputStream configStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(pkcs11configBytes);
etpkcs11 = new SunPKCS11(configStream);
Security.addProvider(etpkcs11);

}
```

the above works
the following doesn't work

```
if(slot ==1) 
{
String pkcs11config1 = "name=Athenaslot1\nlibrary=C:\WINDOWS\system32\asepkcs.dll";
byte[] pkcs11configBytes1 =pkcs11config1.getBytes();
ByteArrayInputStream configStream1 = new ByteArrayInputStream(pkcs11configBytes1);
etpkcs11 = new SunPKCS11(configStream1);
Security.addProvider(etpkcs11);
}
```

the following

```
for(int j=0;j<Security.getProviders().length;j++)
        {
            System.out.println(Security.getProviders()[j].getName());   
        }
```

returns:

```
SunPKCS11-Athena
SunPKCS11-Athenaslot1
SUN
SunRsaSign
SunEC
SunJSSE
SunJCE
SunJGSS
SunSASL
XMLDSig
SunPCSC
```

and the error when using the second the second token:

```
 No installed provider supports this key: sun.security.pkcs11.P11Key$P11PrivateKey
```

Thanks

PS: I need the both tokens on same machine

Answer (score 0):

After having a look at [these docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/p11guide.html) it is saying that the instantiation of the SunPKCS11 can take a slot in the configuration.

So maybe you could try

```
String pkcs11config1 = "name=Athenaslot1\nslot=1\nlibrary=C:\WINDOWS\system32\asepkcs.dll";
```

Comment: I put the slot, even change the name to a new instance  , see: SunPKCS11-Athena, SunPKCS11-Athenaslot1. The first provider contains line slot=0, and the second slot=1.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you add 2 providers to the list of providers, the `SunPKCS11` class caches the first instance. It seems like it always uses this instance all the time. That's the reason your second provider is not picked up/identified.

You might have to write some sneaky code to approach your use case. Right before you use your second provider, you have to clear the cached instance. You can refer to this [post](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3676303) here. It is unanswered, but the code you should be looking for is

```
Field moduleMapField = PKCS11.class.getDeclaredField("moduleMap");  
moduleMapField.setAccessible(true);  
Map<?, ?> moduleMap = (Map<?, ?>) moduleMapField.get(<YOUR_FIRST_PROVIDER_INSTANCE>);  
moduleMap.clear(); // force re-execution of C_Initialize next time
```

What this basically does is clearing the cached instance. And now you can proceed to add your second provider instance to interact with your second token.